# is it posible to button constrained with navigation drawer on android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, navigation-drawer

I want to add button left side of navigation drawer and when navigation drawer animated left the button should be move with navigation button and constained with navigation button [image]

[image]

Comment: constrain button end to start of nav drawer?

Comment: Did you try to do it? :D

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes

Comment: @Vucko yes, and did you think about when writing this comment?

Comment: And what happened? Include relevant XML and the behavior you got

Comment: @Vucko when I arrange drawer layout is a root layout, it isn't imposible to constrained to right view. When I put constraint layout inside drawer layout the button  stay right side. It isn't seen on the screen when right view invisible but I want to see button when right view invisible too

Comment: I think you're going to have to hack around it a bit, but it shouldn't be too hard to do. You can use [this link](http://thetechnocafe.com/slide-content-to-side-in-drawer-layout-android/) to help you. It moves the whole content with the drawer, but you can tweak it slightly to move only 1 view. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically with your own logic. Like you can set a listener for your `NavigationDrawer` and detect position of the drawer, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373562/5701085) is the helping link.

Then you can reposition your button by setting its margins dynamically. You can do it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728484/5701085) way.

Comment: I tried this button moved together with right menu but there is a problem, button stay behind navigation view shadow.