# How can I call a function when navigation drawer is toggled?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to change the items on my navigation drawer based on the user that has logged in and if they have premium account or not.

I know how to make items visible and invisible, but I was wondering if I can put a function somewhere that when ever it's toggled it would set the visibility of them items and also change the header based on the user profile.

thank you all in advance.

Comment: How about when the user signs-in and out?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373562/10452701) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html) to your DrawerLayout

```java
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a DrawerListener to your DrawerLayout

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerToggle());
```

DrawerToggle is an extension of android.support.v4.widget.SimpleDrawerListener in which you've overidden onClick() and onDrawerSlide()

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
 }



@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
}
```

You can use these methods to catch drawer toggle event